# Set DataContext to a property of a StaticResource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a `Controller` class which manages top components:

```
public class FooViewModel {}

public class Controller
{
    public FooViewModel Foo1ViewModel {get; protected set;} // = new ...;
}
```

I have a static resource of the `Controller`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:Controller x:Key="AppController" />
</Application.Resources>
```

And I want Windows and UserControls to have as DataContext properties of `Controller`.

As far as I got is to set the DataContext to the `Controller` itself (which is not what I want)

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="AppController" />
</Window.DataContext>
```

but I cannot set it to a property of it

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <!-- something like this path: -->
    <!--  AppController.Foo1ViewModel -->
</Window.DataContext>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Binding`:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="Foo1ViewModel" Source="{StaticResource AppController}" />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a Binding with the Controller instance as Source:

```
<Window ...
    DataContext="{Binding Foo1ViewModel, Source={StaticResource AppController}}">
```